# root space full How to take backup?

Tags: backup, ubuntu-12.04, diskspace

I 'm using ubuntu and windows in parallel. In my hard disk I left some space for windows and linux also. Now disk apace is full. How can I transfer some data from root to other derive without affecting any applications? plz suggest me the best approch
[I'm attaching the screen shot of disk usage analyzer!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyjmu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same kind of problem and could move the /home partition to some mounted device in 2-steps after logging in as root(On 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS' server).
Step 1: Move /home to /mounteddevice/home
Step 2: Update /etc/passwd file replacing 'home' with 'mounteddevice/home'

And the other directory which consumes more space is /lib and /var/lib and I am searching for a proper solution to move /lib and /var/lib